# Cannot receive push when app is killed Parse FCM

Tags: android, firebase, parsing, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have updated parse sdk which forces me to migrate from GCM to FCM. I have followed this link :
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Push-Notifications-Setup-for-Parse

I am able to receive push notification when app is running or is in background but not when app is killed.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<service
            android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.CustomParsePushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

CustomParsePushReceiver.java

```
public class CustomParsePushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("ParsePushReceiver","Parse receiver received notification");

    }



}
```

I have updated parse server, parse sdk, parse-fcm, firebase-core and firebase-messaging to latest version.

Comment: Which priority have your push messages (normal or high). Do you have some FJD or JobIntentService to wake up the app when a push notification is incoming? Check also https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: post your code on .receiver.CustomParsePushReceiver

Comment: I am just logging in customparsepushreceiver

Comment: Apply the below answer, it will work

Answer (score 0):

**You need to have a separate receiver** for `com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`

Place your other actions (like Boot_Complete) on separate receiver.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some stock ROMs kill all the background processes when the app is killed. Hence the push service is killed and I was not able to receive push when app is killed. Some of those manufacturers are OnePlus, Lenovo, Xiomi, Oppo and Vivo. But when I tested in other devices such as HTC and Samsung it worked !!!

For more info read this blog : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793